# Exponent of submodule is a divisor of the exponent of module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let the exponent of an R-module be the generator of the group of annihilators.
Let R be a PID and M be a torsion R-module with exponent $r \neq 0$.
I want to show that any submodule $N ≤ M$ will have exponent $s$ such that $s\mid r$.

So if M has exponent $r$, then for some $m\in M$, there exists $x \in M$ such that $mxr=0$?

Is that true? How do I link to the exponent of the submodule?

Comment: what is $mxr$ for $m,x \in M$ and $r \in R$? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

If $rm=0$ for all $m\in M$, then $rn=0$ for all $n\in N$. So $r\in Ann_R(N)=Rs$, i.e., $s$ divides $r$.