# Existence of submodule whose exponent is generated by divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a PID and $M$ is a finitely generated torsion $R$-module.

 Let $\exp(M)=(a)$. I need to show that for every $b \in R$ such that $b \mid a$,
there exists a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $\exp(N) = (b)$.

I know that $$\exp(M)=\{r\in R \mid rM=0\},$$
the elements of $R$ that kill the whole of $M$.
I am not really sure how to approach this. There is a converse result at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668103/exponent-of-submodule-is-a-divisor-of-the-exponent-of-module

Comment: So you want a submodule whose elements are annihilated by all multiples of $b$. Why not pick the submodule of elements which are annihilated by all multiples of $b$?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I think the OP may also need some help with proving that your submodule has $(b)$ as its exponent.

Comment: My comment is certainly not a full answer (which is why I did not post it as an answer). I just wanted to give a strong hint, which hopefully also helps OP think about how to approach algebra exercises in the future.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: fair enough, but I don't see that your hint  points anywhere useful: to get the result, you need more precise information about the submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a = bc$, and $m \in M$, then, if $x = yb \in (b)$, then $cm$ satisfies $xcm = ybcm = am = 0$. Conversely if $xcm = 0$, then $xc \in \exp(M) = (a)$ which implies that $xc = ya = ybc$ for some $y$, giving you that $x = yb \in (b)$. So you can take $N = \{cm \mid m \in M\}$.